# Remove count numbers in the text from uniq command | Bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to save a clean list of all repeated lines in my file starting from 50 common elements... and i use this specific command to do that

```
sort file | uniq -cd | awk '$1>50' | sort -nr > output
```

Now i have a list like this sorted by the greater element

```
  12960 <Groan>
   5760 <Snore>
   3985 Talk to <<1>>
   2880 <Nightmare mumble>
   1976 ACCEPT
   1935 Examine
   1744 Yes?
   1733 Hm?
   1701 <<1>>
   1587 What is it?
   1578 What do you want?
   1563 What?
   1514 Well?
   1427 glyph^n
   1189 Examining…
   1019 Now what?
   1010 You again?
   1009 What do you want now?
   1008 <sigh> Again?
    827 Fit only to use for research, or to sell for scrap.
    804 Sack
    792 Back again?
    691 Take
    690 Food
    688 Opening…
    605 Search
    596 Book
    574 Urn
    [...]
```

But what i want is a list like this without the "count number" in my file, in this way i can work on the file more freely...

```
<Groan>
<Snore>
Talk to <<1>>
<Nightmare mumble>
ACCEPT
Examine
Yes?
Hm?
<<1>>
What is it?
What do you want?
What?
Well?
glyph^n
Examining…
Now what?
You again?
What do you want now?
<sigh> Again?
Fit only to use for research, or to sell for scrap.
Sack
Back again?
Take
Food
Opening…
Search
Book
Urn
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
sort file | uniq -cd | awk '$1>50' | sort -nr | grep -oP '^ *[0-9]+ \K.*'
```

Comment: Thank you so much my dear...

Comment: Do you know instead how to reverse the grep command if i'd like to save only the count numbers?

Comment: Replace `grep -oP '^ *[0-9]+ \K.*'` by `awk '{print $1}'`.